# Mistake in worksheet about infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In this [worksheet](http://www.austincc.edu/jthom/SeriesConTestsExer.pdf) I found on the internet, excercise 46, it says $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n} {\ln (2n)}$ diverges.

I thought it should be convergent due to the alternating series test. Another reason is because of the integral test.

So, is there a mistake or am I missing out something fundamental?

Comment: The series converges.

Comment: Yup. So there's a mistake like I thought. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series indeed converges by the alternating series test. Note that the integral test can only determine whether a sequence converges absolutely, but this series doesn't converge absolutely.

Comment: Oh of course, you are right. It works for positive series. Thanks.